# What is the meaning of "internal consistency is 96% alpha"?

Tags: reliability, cronbachs-alpha

> Gilliam Autism Rating Scale (GARS-1)
>   GARS Scale is a checklist that helps identify autistic individuals. Reliability of internal consistency of this scale is 96% alpha.

Part of a psychological paper discusses GARS Scale used to detect autism in individuals. What does the text mean by **"internal consistency of this scale is 96% alpha"**?

Comment: I believe they mean that Cronbach's alpha is 0.96.

Comment: JasonStack Do you have a reference to the paper? It might save us from having to guess at the meaning

Comment: @Glen_b, unfortunately no. It is in Persian. I just translated it literally.